# PHP access to webservice with .cer and .p7b certificates

Tags: php, certificate, soap-client, webservice-client, php-curl

I'm trying to access a webservice from the prefecture that consolidate commercial invoices, the website provides those 2 certificates .cer and .p7b, I've tried both curl and soap clients with several different options in the params array, but still only get 403 or error on loading key.
Can someone explain me which of the certificates I should use, or if both, which goes in which option and others params needed?

Using curl I at least get a 403 answer (which is something expected without the certificate), but on soap client it only gives SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL even it's the very same URL.

Trying loading the keys leads to:
.CER: "unable to set private key file ... type PEM"
.P7B: "could not load PEM client certificate, OpenSSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory, (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?)"
though the path seems to be correct.

Get same errors using cmd line curl with --cert options (though I tried each cert file individually, is there a way to use both simultaneously?)

Comment: obs: the website also provides a manual, but it's pretty lame, just gives a brief explanation about certificates but nothing specific about the usage of the certificates or even about those 2 certs files itself, so I guess won't help posting it here (besides it's in brazillian portuguese)